# VBA Do While...Loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am learning VBA now and have a little problem with a code.

When clicking the button, the program should read the values from the first column until an empty row appears and show them in a Label. This action must be executed only once, that means, the values must not be repeated. Also, if the first cell is already empty, the program must show a message in the Label telling the user, that there are no values to be read. Previously read values must not be shown anymore.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub btn_Werte_einlesen_Click()
Dim znr As Long
znr = 1
Do While Range("A" & znr) <> ""
    
    lbl_Anzeige = lbl_Anzeige & Range("A" & znr) & vbLf
   
    znr = znr + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looks like you have it all figured out. After the loop just do something like `If znr = 1 Then lbl_Anzeige = 'No values to be read'`

Comment: Okay, so we see your code, and we see what you want it to do.  The two things we *don't* have are A) What your "little problem" *is*, and B) What, specifically, you want help with.

Comment: Hi BigBen! Thank you for your answer. I've just tryed it out, but the values will be showed everytime i push the button. It must happen only once, no matter how many times you click it. Just in case the values change, the new values shoul be shown.:(